# Angular component inheritance, keep parent html

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular2-template

I use a lot of inheritance between my Angular components.

Sometimes, I would like to be able to inherit from a specific component, and not provide some html for the child (because it is always going to be the same as the parent) which leads to duplicate code everywhere.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
export class Parent {

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: '', <-- you have to provide a template
})
export class Child extends Parent {

}
```

Comment: still use `templateUrl: './parent.component.html',`? any reason you do not want to do this?

Comment: Yes of course this is one solution but I want my component to be as easy as possible to inherit, and for someone new jumping into the project, the mistake of not replacing the `templateUrl` path can be done.

Comment: As ABOS said, but also note, you can use relative paths to reference the parent HTML if it's in a different directory.

Comment: `../../parent.component.html` to go back/up two directories. It gets messy fairly fast though.

Comment: Oh okay my bad I read it wrong. Yes of course relative paths but its in complete different folders. I am really open to the cleanest way of achieving this. I was thinking about writing a constant in the parent that returns the path of the parent template

Comment: You cannot use absolute paths, so yeah, a constant might work. Wait, that doesn't make sense, I'm contradicting myself, I don't think it'll work afaik.

Comment: What are you trying to extend? The component logic, or just the styling?

Comment: So this is for `ag-grid` table components. I mainly extend the logic. I define all the logic on how to fetch data, achieve paging etc... At the end the html is always the same, and the developer should not worry about copy/pasting it in each new component he creates.

Comment: I'd have to see a more explicit example, but in theory you should be able to do all the work in the *containing* component and pass the result into this *reusable* component for displaying only. That's the dumb component philosophy anyway... Alternatively, you might be able to achieve what you want using directives?

Comment: By containing component you mean the `child` right ?
And what do you mean by directives ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189904/discussion-between-richard-dunn-and-scaraux).

Answer (score 2):

You can modify default component behavior to use template from base class, e.g.

```
function MyComponent(cfg: any) {
  return function (constructor: Function) {
    let base = (Object.getPrototypeOf(constructor.prototype).constructor);
    cfg.template = (<any>base).__annotations__[0].template;
    return Component(cfg)(constructor);
  }
}

@MyComponent({
  selector: 'my-app-child',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppChildComponent extends AppComponent {

}
```

a simple demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swaanp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

PS I don't recommend this approach :)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your share.